# Merge multiple lines using regexp

Tags: regex, go

I have below file. I need to merge all lines ending with backslach (\) and display as a single line.

`abcd  efgh \ ijkl \ mnop  qrst \ uvw  xyz`

Output should look like.
`abcd efgh ijlk mnop qrst uvw xyz`

I am trying to search a pattern on multiple lines.

Comment: Can your provide a proper example for your input? Your example doesn't have multiple lines. In general, it doesn't seem as you needed regexp at all. Wouldn't `strings.ReplaceAll(input, "\\", "\n")` suffice? Or can slashes appear in the middle of a line as well?

Comment: What have you tried? Include your code. What problems did you encounter?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace them this way.
`\r?` before `\n` is optional in case you are using windows.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    str := `abcd 
efgh \
ijkl \
mnop 
qrst \
uvw 
xyz`

    re := regexp.MustCompile(`\\\r?\n`)
    fmt.Println(re.ReplaceAllString(str, ""))

}
```

output:

```
abcd
efgh ijkl mnop
qrst uvw
xyz
```

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly, you have a file with some text written on it and need to apply a regex to merge all the lines and remove backslashes. Something like this may work:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
file, err := os.Open("input.txt")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
defer file.Close()

scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
mergedLine := ""
for scanner.Scan() {
    line := scanner.Text()
    if strings.HasSuffix(line, "\\") {
        mergedLine += strings.TrimSuffix(line, "\\")
    } else {
        mergedLine += line
        fmt.Println(mergedLine)
        mergedLine = ""
    }
}
if mergedLine != "" {
    fmt.Println(mergedLine)
    }
}
```